# Cant display $scope array of objects in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have this weird problem that i cant display my scope variable values. I am new with angular but i have done this many times before. So here is main parts of index.html. div-ui is inside of body but it doesn't see here:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUsers" placeholder="Search users"/>
<a ng-click="search()" ui-sref="search">Search</a>

<div ui-view>

</div>
```

Here is search.html:

```
<p>Hello world</p> // Shows normally
<p>{{test1}}</p> // Shows normally
<p>{{test2}}</p> // Nothing
<p ng-repeat="x in searchResult">{{x.username}}</p> // Nothing
<p ng-repeat="(key,value) in searchResult">{{value}}</p> // Nothing
<p ng-repeat="(key,value) in searchResult">{{value.username}}</p> // Nothing
```

Here is the controller:

```
(function(){
angular.module('TimeWaste')
    .controller('NavigationCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$state",
    function($scope,$http,$state){

        $scope.searchResult = [];
        // Tried with and without this

        if(localStorage['User-Data']){
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
        }else{
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
        }

        $scope.logUserIn = function(){
            $http.post('api/user/login', $scope.login)
                .success(function(response){
                    localStorage.setItem('User-Data', JSON.stringify(response));
                    $scope.loggedIn = true;
                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }

        $scope.logOut = function (){
            localStorage.clear();
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
        }

        $scope.test1 = "hi";

        $scope.search = function (){

             $scope.test2 = "hi again";

            $http.post("api/user/search", {username: $scope.searchUsers})
                .success(function(response){

                    $scope.searchResult = response;
                    console.log($scope.searchResult); 
         // returns array of objects. There is all information that i want.

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log("ei");
                });
        }
    }]);
}());
```

Everything looks just normal. Inside of search function it's working and console.log returns just what i except. I have also tried repeat divs and tables but i am pretty sure that it's not the problem here.

Here is also my app.js if the problem is there:

```
(function(){
angular.module('TimeWaste', ['ui.router', 'ngFileUpload'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("main", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "app/main/main.html",
                controller: "MainCtrl"
            })
            .state("search", {
                url: "/search",
                templateUrl: "app/main/search.html",
                controller: "NavigationCtrl"
            })
    });
}());
```

There is couple more states and they all works just fine. I made it little bit shorter so this post won't be so long.

Comment: `$scope.searchResult = response.data`?

Comment: @Frost  can you attach a sample response here that would be helpul

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work

Comment: @vickyKumar here is example, this is copy from console.log: Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"57f07a9873023b15f016346c"
bio
:
"jea"
email
:
"ville"
followers
:
Array[0]
following
:
Array[0]
image
:
"/uploads/57f07a9873023b15f016346c147537894901.jpg"
password
:
"ville"
username
:
"moro"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with prototypal inheritance. Try using an container object for your vars. `$scope.data.test1` and then `{{data.test1}}`. If this actually fixes your issue I can go into more detail as to what is going on.

Comment: @Frostbch why we are calling search on anchor tag itself caw we do it otherwise 
like on click of anchor we just navigate and on onload of search.html call search()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're able to see `{{test1}}` and not other values is because you have 2 different controllers called 'MainCtrl' and 'NavigationCtrl'. You are using `ui-sref` to switch states. So, this is what happening.

1. When you click your href link, it looks for `search()` method inside your MainCtrl and then change the state to "search".
2. It then loads the variables and methods from NavigationCtrl into scope and that's why you're able to see `{{test1}}` which is loaded into the scope. But you haven't called `search()` method and hence you're not able to see the other values.

To check my answer, call your method explicitly inside your controller after your function definition `$scope.search();`

If you're seeing the result then that is your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is working. I am now able to see test1 and test2. For some reason {{x.username}} doesn't show anything but now it's easier to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, at this very point you must add an $scope.$apply or use '.then' instead of 'success' to keep your code according **promise** pattern.
When you just post, there is a need to force the **digest cycle** to happen.

```
$http.post("api/user/search", {username: $scope.searchUsers})
    .success(function(response){
       $scope.$apply(function() {
           $scope.searchResult = response;
        });
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log("ei");
    });
```

Comment: Now it gives bunch of errors with that. angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Comment: Frostbch. remove your .success and uses '.then(functionSuccess, functionError);'
this is what Angularjs docs recommend to use.